# Push items to knockout observableArray inside ajax request success function

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, wijmo

In my application I want to add items from ajax response to `knockout`'s observableArray. My html:

```
<select id="mySelect" data-bind="options: MyArray"></select>
```

So I have simple viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = { MyArray: ko.observableArray() };
```

and inside after in my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $.ajax({
        url: "MyUrl",
        type: "GET",
        success: function () {
            viewModel.MyArray.push('foo');
        }
    });
});
```

And then nothing happened. In case if I change this code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    viewModel.MyArray.push('foo');
});
```

Everything works fine. (This is only easy example of course).

How can I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I've made some mistake, couse the problem was wijmo. It change select to div and I must invoke

```
 $("#mySelect").wijdropdown('refresh');
```

After adding elements.

Comment: when is your viewmodel created?

Comment: Before `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Is the ready event fired ?

Comment: Are you sure that your `success` gets called?

Comment: Both `ready` and `success` are fired I have checked them using `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `success` parameter within your `$.ajax` call to `complete` to execute when the request finishes, regardless of success or failure. Use the code below to examine the status of your request to help determine why it is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $.ajax({
        url: "MyUrl",
        type: "GET",
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            viewModel.MyArray.push('foo');

            window.console.log(jqXHR);
            window.console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** If this is not the problem, try initializing your observable array with the following:

```
MyArray: ko.observableArray([])
```

Comment: As I wrote in comments `success` is fired so changing it for `complete` doesn't change anythink.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski maybe try it once more just to be sure? Without a jsFiddle I think it's going to be difficult to help your further...

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/hEjWz/

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: MyArray"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = { MyArray: ko.observableArray() };

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                viewModel.MyArray.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This works perfectly. My suggestion would be to inspect network traffic and see if your ajax request actually completes successfully.

Comment: Oops... Forgot references to jquery and ko in the fiddle. Updated it now.